# Padding not working in CSS even with display inline-block

Tags: html, css

Not sure what I was doing wrong, but the padding style in these label/input and button element is not working at all as nothing has changed when I refresh chrome over and over. After searching up online I've only found solution for adding display: inline-block to these elements, but it is still not working. Please see the entirety of my codes below:

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  padding: 10px auto 10px 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.bold {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  margin: auto 4px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #da1e1e;
  color: #da1e1e;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px auto;
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #da1e1e;
  color: white;
}

form {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>New Patient Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="">
    <h1>Register as a New Patient</h1>
    <label class="bold" for="full name">Full Name</label>
    <input class="block" type="text" id="full name" name="full name" placeholder="e.g. George Lucas" required/>
    <label class="block bold">Sex</label>
    <label class="change"><input name="sex" type="radio" value="male" required />Male</label
      >
      <label class="change"
        ><input name="sex" type="radio" value="female" required />Female</label
      >
      <label class="change"
        ><input name="sex" type="radio" value="other" required />Other</label
      >
      <label class="block bold" for="date of birth">Date of Birth</label>
    <input class="block" type="date" id="date of birth" name="date of birth" required/>
    <label class="block bold" for="email address">Email Address</label>
    <input class="block" type="email" id="email address" name="email address" placeholder="e.g. g.lucas@gmail.com" required/>
    <button type="submit">Submit Details</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there is no auto value for padding. replace it with 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as padding `auto`.

Because of that, the entire padding line is invalid and is not being utilized.

You can also see this when you inspect an element. You'll notice it's crossed out with a warning sign next to it:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing auto in padding.

Change to this:

```
.block{
padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

Can see this error in inspect:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

'auto' means automatically adjusted. It goes with width, height, margin & background-size. NOT with padding.

```
padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
```

Just set it to `0px` instead of auto & it should work now.

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input class="block" type="text" id="full name" name="full name" placeholder="e.g. George Lucas" required />
```